# Understanding a proof $f(\bigcup \mathfrak{C})\subseteq \bigcup f(\mathfrak{C})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I want to show you an example what my [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201756110) says

> If $f:X\to Y$, $\mathfrak{C}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, then
>   $f(\bigcup \mathfrak{C})=\bigcup f(\mathfrak{C})$.
>
> Proof: (..) Let $y\in f(\bigcup \mathfrak{C})$. There is an $x\in \bigcup
>  \mathfrak{C}$ such that $f(x)=y$, and so $y\in f(C)$ for some $C\in
>  \mathfrak{C}$. Thus $y\in \bigcup f(\mathfrak{C})$, proving that
>   $f(\bigcup \mathfrak{C})\subseteq \bigcup f(\mathfrak{C})$. (..)

I know well how to prove it another way. I just want to understand this proof technique better. The only part I don't understand is how the author chose to imply this part "... and so $y\in f(C)$ for some $C\in
 \mathfrak{C}$" all sudden. Where does it come from?

**Edit**: I'll add more what I'm asking about. If I'm writing it formally from the proof, my understanding is 
\begin{align}
y\in f(\bigcup \mathfrak{C}) &\iff y=f(x) \textrm{ for some } x\in \bigcup \mathfrak{C}\tag{1}\\
&\iff y=f(x) \textrm{ for some } \left [ x\in C \textrm{ for some } C\in \mathfrak{C} \right ]\tag{2}\\
&\stackrel{?}\implies y\in f(C) \textrm{ for some } C\in \mathfrak{C}\tag{3}\\
&\iff y\in \bigcup f(\mathfrak{C}).
\end{align}
I can see that the proof has not mention about $(2)$. Is $(2)$ mathematically correct to write that way? Should $(2)$ be replaced by $(3)$? If yes, why? What would you do if you were asked to prove it with this similar technique? I apologize if I am asking too much.

Answer (score 1):

$x\in\bigcup\mathfrak C$ *means* that $x\in C$ for some $C\in\mathfrak C$. Therefore, since $f(x)=y$ and $x\in C$ we have $y\in f(C)$ for that particular $C$.